# Illustrator: align objects by anchor point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, illustrator-scripting, guides

I'd like to align objects such that a single anchor point in each object are aligned, dragging the rest of each object with them. For example, going from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I've eyeballed it here to illustrate, but is there a way to accomplish this accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have smart guides and snap to pixels enabled. Then drag a guide from rulers (if not visible hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) into the scene to align on one of the points. Select the object and start dragging with the direct selection tool (white arrow) from the corner point while holding down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, until it snaps to your guide.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it in my opinion is illustrated below.

1. Take your original shapes, and add those lines to it.
2. Draw a box, centred about that line. Make sure it's wider than the original shape. Group the box, line, and outline.
3. Select the shapes and click the vertical align button.
4. Delete extra shapes as necessary.

[image: Align Problem]

Comment: I wish I had thought of this. Clever!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to first construct the objects along the same vertical guide (see image) and **then** rotate by anchor points. When you select an object, hit the <kbd>R</kbd> key to choose the rotate tool, then **click** a corner of the object touching the guide (see where it says *anchor* in the image below). This locks the rotation around that specific point, instead of the object center. So you rotate while keeping that corner **locked** in place (see [video](https://youtu.be/-GaTsh1eoeo?t=7) for more tricks).

*note: similar to @joojaa's answer, but in reversed order*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select top anchor with direct selection tool (A) and copy (CTRL+C)
2. Select hole object with selection tool (V) and lock it (Ctrl+2)
3. Past in front (Ctrl+F) of your previous copy anchor and  eliminate other two anchor associate with top anchor
4. Please don't forget to active smart guides (Ctrl+U) and snap to point (Ctrl+Alt+"). If you hide bounding box (Ctrl+Shift+B) it's very good but not necessary.
5. Now select and drug your object with pressing "Ctrl" then you can see smart guides show align reference to your targeted top single anchor.
6. After alignment please delete single anchor and unlock your object.

I hope in this way you can align any object to any anchor point.
Thanks